# Jquery Fade In/Out Div Switcher Won't Display Right in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Basically how this is supposed to work (and does in firefox, safari, and chrome) is that there are three links in a list and when you click one, its class is used to find a div with the same name but in an id. That `div` is then faded in after all `divs` with a certain class are faded out (this `div` has to class as well as a catch all).

here is the JS code:

```
$(".dynamic_nav li a").click(function() {

    column_switch = $(this).parent().attr('class');

    if($(this).hasClass('active_tab') == true) {
        return false;
    }

    else {
        $(".dynamic_nav li a").removeClass("active_tab");

        $("div.portfolio_section").hide();

        $("#" + column_switch).fadeIn(500);

        $(this).addClass("active_tab");
    }

    return false;
});
```

And my html code:

```
<ul class="dynamic_nav">
    <li class="web"><a class="active_tab" href="#">Web</a></li>
    <li class="print"><a href="#">Print</a></li>
    <li class="advertising"><a href="#">Advertising</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="web" class="portfolio_section"><p>Some Text<p></div>
<div id="print" class="portfolio_section"><p>Some Text<p></div>
<div id="advertising" class="portfolio_section"><p>Some Text<p></div>
```

Comment: What is happening in IE?

Comment: the initial div is displayed, but once I click one of the other links, nothing is displayed, but if I click on the last link (or category) that always works.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here are a few things I noticed that were wrong with the code you posted. After I fixed these it did work in IE.

First your advertising div is missing a closing quote after the class name. Second your li's all are using the same name which is probably something you are aware of already since you said it worked in others. I would check the missing quote to start. Because like I said it is working for me.

Comment: Hi, this is actually just an error with the code I posted. The classes are added dynamically and the missing quotation is present in the original file. The fact that it did work for you is interesting though. I tested in ie6, 7, and 8. Are you using 9?

Comment: No I am using IE 8. Here is the code that I have working for me. I should note I am using jquery 1.3.2.

http://pastebin.com/484qGUjD